# WebSocket The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING]

Tags: java, spring

I'm using tomcat 8.0.15, spring 4.1.5.

I implemented 3 mandatory functions for using websocket like below.
It's very simple.

```
private Map<String, WebSocketSession> map_users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private Map<String, String> map_id = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession wss) throws Exception {
    map_users.put(wss.getId(), wss);
}

public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession wss, CloseStatus cs) throws Exception {
    map_users.remove(wss.getId());

    // remove user
    String username = map_id.get(wss.getId());
    if (username != null) {
        map_id.remove(wss.getId());
        map_id.remove(username);
    }
}

public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession wss, TextMessage tm) throws Exception {
    String str = tm.getPayload();
    String username = ...;

    // regist user
    if (!map_id.get(wss.getId())) {
        map_id.put(wss.getId(), username);
        map_id.put(username, wss.getId());
    }

    for (WebSocketSession w: map_users.values()) {
        w.sendMessage(new TextMessage(wss.getId() + " send to " + w.getId() + ", msg:" + tm.getPayload()));
    }
}
```

Some client sends a message and other clients get the message by the handleTextMessage.

In my case, without the handleTextMessage function, server program wants to send a text message to clients.
(for this I saved a WebSocketSession's Id and username into map_id)

```
String websocketsesssion_id = map_id.get(username);
WebSocketSession wss = map_users.get(websocketsesssion_id);
wss.sendMessage(new TextMessage(new java.util.Date()));
```

Above code works very well.
But when some client's WebSocketSession is in use and try to use simultaneously, it makes error.
It means
    1. some client send message --> handleTextMessage is called --> the client's WebSocketSession is using
    2. server program wants to send message to that client --> get the client's WebSocketSession from map --> try to send message with the same WebSocketSession

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.checkState(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1092)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.textPartialStart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1050)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:218)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.sendMessageInternal(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendMessage(AbstractSockJsSession.java:161)
```

As the result, WebSocketSession is closed and client has to open new WebSocketSession again.

So, my question is:

Can I check whether the WebSocketSession is in use or not?
(outside the handleTextMessage function)

Answer (score 33):

The problem is that several thread try to write in same time on the socket so :

try :

```
String websocketsesssion_id = map_id.get(username);
WebSocketSession wss = map_users.get(websocketsesssion_id);
synchronized(wss) {
 wss.sendMessage(new TextMessage(new java.util.Date()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While synchronizing `sendMessage()` calls helps for ws:// connection, it doesn't help for `wss://, i.e. SSL/TLS connection`. It is 100% failure if you trying send partial messages while reading partial messages. I have tested it on Spring Boot 1.4.2 RELEASE (tomcat 8.5.6)

The same with tomcat 8.5.9. See the trace stack below.

```
[pool-18-thread-1] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Sending message to the endpoint: 
[pool-18-thread-2] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Sending message to the endpoint: 
[pool-18-thread-3] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Sending message to the endpoint: 

[https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] [FrontendWebSocketHandler] Message from 0, isLast: false, length: 16384
[https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] [FrontendWebSocketHandler] Message from 0, isLast: false, length: 16384

[pool-18-thread-3] [FrontendWebSocketHandler] Transport error. Session: StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=/myt/websocket]
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to wrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:258)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:104)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.websocket.FrontendWebSocketHandler.send(FrontendWebSocketHandler.java:180)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.websocket.FrontendWebSocketHandler.send(FrontendWebSocketHandler.java:24)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.GenericMessageEndpoint.sendMessage(GenericMessageEndpoint.java:72)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.GenericMessageEndpoint.send(GenericMessageEndpoint.java:57)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.MessageSender.process(MessageSender.java:24)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:47)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.mytreasury.services.backend.AbstractTopicMessageHandler.handle(AbstractTopicMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.message.handler.ResponseGenericMessageHandler.handle(ResponseGenericMessageHandler.java:52)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.socket.EventPublisherSocketHandler.handle(EventPublisherSocketHandler.java:96)
    at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.socket.EventPublisherSocketHandler$1$1.run(EventPublisherSocketHandler.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to wrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:647)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1241)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:95)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:309)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
[https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] [FrontendWebSocketHandler] Transport error. Session: StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=/myt/websocket]
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:981)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:563)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1195)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1168)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: bad record MAC
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:974)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
[pool-18-thread-3] [FrontendWebSocketHandler] Connection closed. Session: StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=/myt/websocket], CloseStatus: CloseStatus[code=1006, reason=Unable to wrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]];
[pool-18-thread-2] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Exception while sending message to the endpoint: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method,
[pool-18-thread-1] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Exception while sending message to the endpoint: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method, 
[pool-18-thread-3] [GenericMessageEndpoint] Exception while sending message to the endpoint: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to wrap data, invalid status [CLOSED],
```

Comment: Does it mean there is no solution if you use `wss://` ?

Comment: Why sending message and reading message can't run simultaneously? `TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING` is to prevent the client side reading a mixed text response, so it has to be one message at a time. But server side reading?  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **TEXT_PARTIAL_READY** the websocket session may be already in **State.TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING** by another thread, as shown in the code here

https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c666c3d1095a50001c2b6f4#L1182